# How to dynamically read the json nested elements in java

Tags: java, json

Getting the response from the API request, and read the response like

```
response.jsonPath().getString("results[0].overview.birthPlace.address.streetAddress")
```

And from another API request, the response contains street address like

```
response.jsonPath().getString("results[0].overview.address[0].streetAddress")
```

Is there any unique way of getting the streetAddress in both the cases.

I tried with

```
response.jsonPath().getString("$.results[0].overview..streetAddress")
```

But not successes, returns null.

Comment: Try this: https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.json.JSONObject/keys

Comment: Can you please post a sample JSON on which this query is being run?